# Project Euler 22: Names scores by Loki

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++17

Started working through Project Euler this weekend.

[Project Euler 22](https://projecteuler.net/problem=22)

> Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text
>   file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it
>   into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for
>   each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the
>   list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN,
>   which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the
>   list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <numeric>
#include "PunctFacet.h"

using ThorsAnvil::Util::PunctFacet;

long scoreName(std::string const& name)
{
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(name), std::end(name), 0L, 
                           [](long v1, char x){return v1 + x - 'A' + 1;});
}

int main()
{
    // Open a file that considers " and , as space and thus ignores them
    std::ifstream   data;
    data.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new PunctFacet(std::locale(), "\",")));
    data.open("euler/e22.data");

    // read all the names in a set (its sorted) 
    std::set<std::string> names{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(data),
                                std::istream_iterator<std::string>()};

    // Calculate the result
    long    score   = 0;
    long    loop    = 1;
    for(auto name: names) {
        score += (loop * scoreName(name));
        ++loop;
    }
    std::cout << score << "\n";
}
```

#### PunctFacet.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_UTIL_PUNCT_FACET_H
#define THORSANVIL_UTIL_PUNCT_FACET_H

#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Util
    {

// This is my facet that will treat the characters in `extraSpace`
// as space characters and thus ignore them with formatted input
class PunctFacet: public std::ctype<char>
{
    public:
        typedef std::ctype<char>    base;
        typedef base::char_type     char_type;

        PunctFacet(std::locale const& l, std::string const& extraSpace)
            : base(table)
        {
            std::ctype<char> const&  defaultCType  = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(l);

            // Copy the default value from the provided locale
            static  char data[256];
            for(int loop = 0;loop < 256;++loop) { data[loop] = loop;}
            defaultCType.is(data, data+256, table);

            // Modifications to default to include extra space types.
            for(auto space: extraSpace) {
                table[space]  |= base::space;
            }
        }
    private:
        base::mask  table[256];
};

    }
}

#endif
```

#### Results

```
> g++ -O3 -std=c++14 euler/e22.cpp
> time ./a.out
871198282

real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`#include <numeric>`**!

I see no reason why individual score is computed via `std::accumulate`, but the total uses a loop. I recommend `std::inner_product` there, at least for consistency.

Similarly, the

```
        for(int loop = 0;loop < 256;++loop) { data[loop] = loop;}
```

is

```
        std::iota(data, data + 256, 0);
```

Of course, a magic `256` shall be replaced by a symbolic name.

I don't feel comfortable with `std::set` used just to avoid sorting. It  obscures the intention. You seem to have the same feeling, and put the clarifying comment. I recommend to be explicit: read the names into a vector, and sort it. BTW, it would also reduce space requirements.

Comment: The magic 256 could be avoided by using `std::begin` and `std::end`...

Comment: `std::iota()` learn something new every day.

Comment: @Deduplicator I didn't mean just this one line. 256 in a declaration of `data` is also magic.

Answer (score 5):

### Include your own headers before standard headers

I'd write:

```
#include "PunctFacet.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <numeric>
```

That way, if you accidentally forget a necessary definition in your own header (by virtue of an earlier include happening to provide it), you increase your chances of discovering it at an early stage.

### Avoid magic constants

Where does that `256` come from?  If it's supposed to be equal to `base::table_size`, then just use the constant, to be consistent with the base class.

### Review visibility of types

I don't see a need to make the `base` type public - it seems that this is provided for implementation convenience only (and it tends to get confusing when you have a hierarchy where many, but not all, classes provide such a member).

### Spell-check your comments

```
// read all the names in a set (it's sorted)
                                ^^^^
```

(Okay, I'm over-doing it now!)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why `data` in `ThorsAnvil::Util::PunctFacet::PunctFacet` is static instead of automatic storage class.

I also wonder why you don't use your `base`-typedef in that ctor.

Comment: this should be a comment - not an answer

Comment: Only person to spot the static member in the class constructor +1. Yep I'll remove that use of `base` in the constructor.